# Why I should declare bean on constructor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class ServiceA on project-a:

```
public class ServiceA {
    
    private ModelA modelA;
    
    public ServiceA(ModelA modelA) {
        this.modelA = modelA;
    }
}
```

modelA from other local library (external library). modelA have @Component annotation

when I run this code, cannot found error bean on ModelA. I solve with add @Bean for ModelA on project-a.
Why I should add bean? because the ModelA on external library? Any reference link for I can understand for this case? I want understand for this code. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is because ModelA component is on external library. By default Spring Boot scans for compontents  withing `@SpringBootApplication`-annotated class's package and sub-packages. Using `@ComponentScan(basePackages=//multiple packages)` on any of configuration classes should help.

Comment: So, I if put basePackages with modelA packages, I should not put @Bean on ModelA right? any link reference for I learn?

Comment: Add to your question the package of the ServiceA and ModelA classes.  Also, include the component scanning configuration in your module.

Answer (score 0):

The first comment is the most likely answer to your issue;
specifically,
the component scanning that is configured in your project does not include the package that contains the `modelA` class.